# Visually grouping labels and buttons

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios5

In Apple's Contacts app, if you go to a contact that has two emails or two phone numbers, the buttons will share a center border and the button on top will have rounded corners on top while the one on bottom will have rounded corners there.

How can I do this? I'd like to do it with both buttons and labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you create a UITableView, you can make its style "Grouped". And a grouped tableView will give you the desired rounded corners automatically (look at the method `initWithFrame:style:` with `UITableViewStyleGrouped`)

Comment: I had been using a UIView instead of a UITableView - will a TableView allow me to make some of the cells buttons and some of them labels?

Comment: I really can't recommend [QuickDialog](http://escoz.com/open-source/quickdialog) library enough. It's extremely easy-to-use and really simplifies the creation of any type of forms (sounds like that's what you're trying to do in the question).